# Swashbuckle issue with OpenID

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, openid-connect, swashbuckle

I've configured Swashbuckle (5.0.0-rc2) on ASP.NET Core to work with my OpenID server (Openiddict) but Swagger doesn't show any available authorization.
Only an empty modal.

This is the snippet where I set OpenID on swagger

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    //... omitted for brevity
    //baseAccountsUrl is "https://localhost:5401"

    c.AddSecurityDefinition("AccountsOpenID", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OpenIdConnect,
        OpenIdConnectUrl = new Uri($"{baseAccountsUrl}/.well-known/openid-configuration")
    });
}
```

If I login before getting here every action works fine, otherwise every method will be redirected to login and shown in server response.

If I use OAuth2 instead of OpenID with password flow (it's configured this way on Openiddict) and not logged-in in browser it's not successful either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if things have changed on the   (5.0.0-rc2) but on the older version you needed to implement a custom IDocumentFilter and/or IOperationFilter to set the security properties:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.WebHost/Nuget/Content/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs.pp#L54

Comment: I have to move the OpenID server to another project, before this split everything works fine, after that Swagger authenticated correcly with OAuth 2 so I tried to update to version 5.0.0-rc2 with OpenID support but OpenID seems to not work, it shows an empty Available Authorization on main lock button. OAuth continues not authenticating like version 4.x.

Answer (score 2):

Support for OpenID Connect Discovery was added in Swagger UI v. 3.38.0. Swashbuckle needs to update the bundled Swagger UI to the latest version:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1241